# How to prove that if a figure in a number changes, then the rest also changes.

Tags: arithmetic

We have a 8 figure number, lets call it $N_1=a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6a_7a_8$. Prove that if we interchange two numbers (for example $N_2=a_1a_2a_4a_3a_5a_6a_7a_8$ and $N_1 \neq N_2$) then the rest we get by dividing $N_1$ and $N_2$ with 23 isn't the same.
Then prove that if we change one number (for example: $N_3=a_1a_2ba_4a_5a_6a_7a_8$ and $b\neq a_3$) the rest we get by dividing $N_1$ and $N_3$ by 23 is not the same.

Then prove that this is not true if we divide the numbers by 24. I mean, that we can find $N_1, N_2$ and $N_3$ defined as I said before that after dividing by 24 the rest is the same.

I do not even know how to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the first claim isn't true as stated...since nothing prevents $a_3=a_4$.  If you add the condition that $a_i\neq a_j$, then $N_1-N_2=(a_i-a_j)\times 10^{8-i}-(a_j-a_i)10^{8-j}$. (Note:  check the exponents there). Work from there.

Comment: Side note:  life (or at least arithmetic) gets easier if you change notation to  $N_1=a_7a_6\cdots a_0=\sum a_i10^i$.

Comment: @lulu I edited it. Not all the figures have to be different, but the new number $N_2$ can't be the same as $N_1$ (so the interchanged figures can not be the same figure).

Comment: Sure.  As I said, I figured you meant to add that condition.

Comment: @lulu I do not know what that subtraction has to do with the rest. I don't understand why this changes when the dividing number is 24. I suppose that it is something related to prime numbers, as 23 is prime. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: To say that $N_1,N_2$ have the same remainder $\pmod m$ is to say that $N_1-N_2\equiv 0 \pmod m$, so the subtraction is natural.

Comment: @lulu So $\frac {N_1-N_2}{23}$ can't be natural? Why?

Comment: Please study the hint I wrote in my first comment.  It is very nearly a complete solution.

Comment: @lulu Ok. Just one thing. Wouldn't it be $(a_i-a_j)10^{8-i} + (a_j-a_i)10^{8-j}$ ?